# In AWS s3, can I get the latest files written using the last marker I've stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName);
ObjectListing listing = null;

while((listing == null) || (request.getMarker() != null)) {
listing = s3Client.listObjects(request);
// do stuff with listing
 request.setMarker(listing.getNextMarker()); //ALSO STORE MARKER FOR FUTURE USE
}
```

I do this to consume all the files in a folder. Now after a period of time, I'd like to use the stored marker to fetch only the new files written in that folder. Would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't help you, for a couple of reasons:

- The marker is just a lexical marker.  Object keys are returned in lexical ("alphabetical") order (binary sort by the utf-8 encoded representation of the object key), not the order of object creation.
- On the last response, the response is not truncated, so the next marker should be null or otherwise not set.

From the API Reference of the service actually called by the SDK:

> `NextMarker`
>
> When the response is truncated (that is, the `IsTruncated` element value in the response is true), you can use the key name in this field as a marker in the subsequent request to get next set of objects. Amazon S3 lists objects in UTF-8 character encoding in lexicographical order.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: Can the requied behavior be achieved by some other way?
And if we assume that the new objects will always be lexicographocally greater (like logs), can we detect new objects?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround which I could find, and is only applicable if we have control over the naming of object's keys being stored in the buckets.

- Append some accending prefix (like current timestamp) to your object keys, to ensure the new objects comes after the old ones in lexicographical order.
- Instead of using the *nextMarker*, we can also use the ***last object's key*** itself as marker in the next request.

> ...you can use the value of the last Key in the response as the marker in the subsequent request to get the next set of object keys.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html

Though this is AWS cli's documentaion, I've verified the same behavior through Java SDK.